# notepad++ regex how to extract userId from this list

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this list below:

```
originalscrape,scrapeDate,userId,username,full_name,is_private,follower_count,following_count,media_count,biography,hasProfilePic,external_url,email,contact_phone_number,address_street,isbusiness,Engagement %,MostRecentPostDate,AvgLikes,AvgComments,category,businessJoinDate,businessCountry,businessAds,countryCode,cityName,isverified
,07/03/2020 05:54 AM,="189389157",stronger_together_forever,stronger_together_forever ☀️,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
,07/03/2020 05:54 AM,="51807820",aaronistattoo,Aaron Is.,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
,07/03/2020 05:54 AM,="194962598",djcoley727,djcoley727,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
,07/03/2020 05:54 AM,="4182106610",cesararce1985,Cesar Arce,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
,07/03/2020 05:54 AM,="8957742561",minkwhiz,,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,No,0,Has no posts.,0,0,,,,,,,No
```

I would like to get the userIds only as below:

```
189389157
51807820
194962598
4182106610
8957742561
```

I've used `^(?:[^,\r\n]*,){3}([^,\r\n]+).*` but it gets me "Usernames", I want is Userids.

I wish somebody who can help me to find the right Regex to extract the userids only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use Match the `="` and repeat the group 2 times instead of 3. Then capture 1+ digits.

Note to repeat the character class `[^,\r\n]` using `*` for 0 or more times.

If you want the digits only, you could replace with group 1 using `$1`

```
^(?:[^,\r\n]*,){2}="(\d+)".*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^,\r\n]*,){2}` Repeat 2 times matching 0 or more times any char except a comma or a newline, then match `,`
- `="` Match literally
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- `".*` Match " and match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5lDOLG/1)

---

If you want the match only, you could make use of `\K` to reset the match buffer, then match the digits and assert a double quote on the right.

```
^(?:[^,\r\n]*,){2}="\K\d+(?=")
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jeaoHV/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the advantage the time in the `AM/PM` format is present *before* each ID as well as the ID is surrounded with `"` characters:

```
(?:AM|PM),=\"(\d+)\"
```

Check the demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/43a9ma/1).