# Notepad++ regex to extract usernames from this list

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this list below:

```
scrapeDate,username,full_name,is_private,follower_count,following_count,media_count,biography,hasProfilePic,external_url,email,contact_phone_number,address_street,category,businessJoinDate,businessCountry,businessAds,countryCode,cityName,isverified
07/05/2020 05:37 AM,maplethenorwich,Maple the Norwich,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,,,,,,,No
07/05/2020 05:37 AM,baby_yoda_militia,Baby Yoda,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,,,,,,,No
07/05/2020 05:37 AM,caciquegoldendoodle,CaciqueGoldenDoodle,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,,,,,,,No
07/05/2020 05:37 AM,ja_watts,Julie Anna Watts,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,,,,,,,No
07/05/2020 05:37 AM,lets_go_zumba_and_travel,Mrsirenetakamoto,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,,,,,,,No
07/05/2020 05:37 AM,bunnyslash,Bunnyslash,False,0,0,0,,False,,,,,,,,,,,No
```

I would like to get the Usernames only as below:

```
maplethenorwich
baby_yoda_militia
caciquegoldendoodle
ja_watts
lets_go_zumba_and_travel
bunnyslash
```

I've tried `^(?:[^,\r\n]*,){3}([^,\r\n]+).*` but it gets me "False".

I wish somebody who can help me to find the right Regex to extract the Usernames only.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/zmSwea/1) help?

Comment: You have asked a question like this before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62723201/notepad-regex-how-to-extract-userid-from-this-list Did that work out?

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
.*?,(.*?),.*
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`.*?`** - **Lazily** matches everything except the new line.
- **`,`** - Matches `,` literally.
- **`(.*?)`** - Represents first capturing group matching **lazily** `username` or the second values in csv.
- **`,.*`** - **Greedily** matching everything except new line. *If you don't want to remove the contents; just leave this and capture the above group and write them to a new file or according to your requirement.*
- **`$1`** - For the replacement part replace all the matched text with just the captured group using `$1`.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/zmSwea/1/)

#### Result Snap from notepad++

[image: Pictorial Representation]

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating the group 3 times using quantifier `{3}`, but there is no need to repeat it because you want the second value.

```
^(?:[^,\r\n]*,){3}([^,\r\n]+).*
 ^^^          ^^^^
```

You can omit the quantifier and the non capturing group as there is nothing to repeat.

```
^[^,\r\n]*,([^,\r\n]+).*
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `[^,\r\n]*,` Match 0+ times any char except a comma or newline, then match `,`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^,\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except a comma or newline
- `)` Close group 1
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BDoWev/1)